# Dam integration with youtube in adobe experience manager 6.0 for uploading videos in youtube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, aem, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-channels

I tried to youtube integration with dam.My use case  is upload videos from dam to youtube.Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for this feature (for AEM 6.0) can be found here: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/author/assets/dynamic-media/video.html#Publishing%20videos%20to%20YouTube